# Задать корректную анимацию текста с помощью css

Tags: html, css, анимация, css-animation

Не получается задать корректную анимацию текста с помощью кейфрейма. Текст анимируется один раз, нужно сделать так, чтобы анимация начиналась с начала, плавно доходила до конца и текст полностью оставался, а не исчезал. Цикл анимации один раз.

Вот ссылка на код https://codepen.io/victorbej/pen/JjRQoOz

```
<p>Заголовок какого-либо текста</p>


body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #000;
}

p {
  position: relative;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 2em;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #000, #fff, #000);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 80%;
  animation: animate 8s linear 1;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
}

@keyframes animate {
  0% {
    background-position: -500%;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 500%;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Немного импровизации:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #000;
}

p {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 10px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 2em;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #000, #fff, #000);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 80%;
  background-position: 0%;
  animation: animate 8s linear;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}

@keyframes animate {
  0% {
    background-position: -500%;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  }
  90% {
    background-position: 500%;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  }
  99.999% {
    background-position: 0%;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 0%;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  }
}
```

```html
<p>Заголовок какого-либо текста</p>
```